# Injecting a service into AccountController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, and I am using the default template that MS provides when creating a new project.

I want to add an injected `EmailService` into `AccountController`:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private IEmailService _emailService; // <-- added this field to MS template

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    // I have added emailService to constructor parameter
    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, IEmailService emailService)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        _emailService = emailService; 
    }
```

I am using ninject, and this is how I resolve `IEmailService`:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    try
    {
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
    catch
    {
        kernel.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IEmailService>().To<MyEmailService>().InRequestScope();
}
```

Now, my `emailService` is not getting injected into `AccountController`... so I started debugging the code and noticed that the parameter-less constructor is used to initialize the `AccountController`... but the strange thing is, `userManager` and `signInManager` are still accessible!

For example, I click on Forgot password, the parameter-less constructor initializes `AccountController`, and then the following action method is called (which is part of MVC project template):

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /* UserManager is successfully injected!! */
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

        // some code here to build an email...

        /* _emailService is NULL!! */
        await _emailService.SendEmailAsync(email);
    }
```

**Question 1**: How is it possible `userManager` and `signInManager` are injected through the parameter-less constructor.

**Question 2**: How can I inject my `EmailService` into `AccountController`?

Comment: Remove the parameter less constructor. If your DI wiring up cod is fine, your code will work.

Comment: Thanks @Shyju, please, are you able to explain how is userManager initialized?

Comment: make sure the dependencies are registered in the dependency resolver

Comment: If you check the controller there will be either a property or method that is getting the managers from the owin context if they were not already set in the constructor. That was usually part of the default template

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi... you are right. So if I remove the parameter-less constructor, then I need to resolve userManager and signManager through my own DI container (ninject)?

Comment: @Hooman Yes, via the `IDependencyResolver`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 1: How is it possible userManager and signInManager are injected through the parameter-less constructor.

It is not being injected via parameterless constructor. If you check the controller you will see the `UserManager` and `SignInManager` lazy loading via OWIN context if they were not already set in the constructor.

```
public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager {
    get {
        return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
    private set {
        _signInManager = value;
    }
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
    get {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

That was usually part of the default template.

> Question 2: How can I inject my EmailService into AccountController?

Remove the parameter-less constructor and the lazy loading. Then make sure all dependencies are registered in the dependency resolver so that the object graph can be resolved via the `IDependencyResolver` used by the framework.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

RegisterServices(kernel);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new Ninject.Web.WebApi.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel); //Web API
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver
    .SetResolver(new Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel)); // MVC

return kernel;
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi, I updated my question to show my DI code. So I need to add: System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver
    .SetResolver(new Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel)); to CreateKernel(). But I still need to  code in RegisterServices() to bind MyEmailService to IEmailService, right? Do I need to add any additional bindings for the managers?

Comment: @Hooman If you are keeping the managers as is then no. otherwise you would need to register them as well with the kernel. There are already a lot of easy to find answers on how to set MVC resolver.

Comment: @Hooman the resolver will act as a wrapper for ninject, so register everything with ninject and then wrap that.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did in the end:

```
public AccountController(IEmailService emailService)
{
    _emailService = emailService;
}

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, IEmailService emailService)
    : this(emailService)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
}
```

I didn't change any of the ninject code.